# Create a for loop for extracting specific row from pd dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame with 14columns and 169882 rows. The data frame columns head are

```
Columns: [Station, day, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, Z]
```

There is total of 58 stations in the "Station" column which named from 1 to 58, however, they are randomly distributed through the data frame.

I write the code below to extract the row from dataset for and specific station name ( for example station 1 in code below) and save to a excel file with the station corresponding name:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.Station)
S1= grouped.get_group(1)
S1.to_excel("1.xlsx")
```

how can I create a for loop to read through the "Station" column, extract the rows related to stations 1 to 58 and subsequently save each station output to an excel file? in a simpler manner how to put the upper code in a for loop to do the task for all 58 stations?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in 2 steps, get unique list of station, and then loop through the station and apply filter on the dataframe

```
Station = df['Station'].unique().tolist()

for s in Station:
    file = s + '.csv'
    df1 = df[df.Station == str(s)]
    df1.to_csv(file, index=False)
```